# Send Emails via Excel VBA one at a time

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I am using MS Excel and Outlook 2013.  I am trying to automate an Excel spreadsheet that sends 5 emails to a specified address using Outlook.

The trick is I want each message to display one at a time and only move on to the next message when the user either hits Send or closes the message.  Here is what I have so far:

```
    Sub Send_Emails()

    Dim OutApp As Object: Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Dim OutMail As Object: Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

   'Send Email
   With OutMail
      .to = "john.doe@mycompany.com"
      .Subject = "This is the Subject"
      .Body = "This is message"
      .Display
   End With

   On Error Resume Next:
   OutMail = Nothing
   OutApp = Nothing
   End Sub

   Sub Send_Five_Emails()
   For i = 1 To 5 'Send email 5 times
       Call Send_Emails
   Next i
   End Sub
```

The problem with this code is that it displays all 5 message windows at once. Is there a way to make the Close event of one message window trigger the Displaying of the next one, so as to make them appear one at a time?

I appreciate the help.

Comment: I suppose you could display parts of the message in a MsgBox and then `Send` each message without displaying it (otherwise they'll have both the MsgBox and message-display to respond to). Otherwise, I doubt there is a straightforward way to achieve this. I.e. I suspect it would be *complicated*. Someone may correct me ;)

Comment: check the sent-items folder before _Call Send_Emails_

Comment: There isn't an easy way to do specifically do what you are asking in regards to the window close (without diving deeper into VB.Net). It would help if your actual goal was explained to avoid an XY-Problem. If you just want to "take a peak" (not a technical term!) at each individual message, this below code may work for you...
After your code: `Call Send_Emails` Put two lines: `Dim answr As Byte: answr = MsgBox("Everything Good? Click Okay To continue!", vbOKCancel)` followed by:
       `If answr <> vbOK Then Exit For`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Use **`.Display (True)`***

*The **`expression.Display(Modal)`** argument is used with all objects except for the `Explorer` and `MAPIFolder` objects, **True** to make the window modal. **The default value is False**.*

*[See Display Method on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa220090(v=office.11).aspx)*

Comment: Works like a charm! Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: Thanks for the heads up!  I'm fairly new to asking questions on stack so appreciate the guidance.